# How can I POST JSON to another page and get to that page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, post

Can we only use javascript (`jQuery`, `AnjularJS`, anyhow, but do not use form) to get to another page with some JSON as the POST request body?

It means, I hope to write a segment of javascript code act as a submit button's action code. It will lead me to another page using POST request with some JSON data.

Comment: either post it with form or store data in session

Comment: Show some code, it's very hard to tell what you're asking. Questions without code are not a good fit for SO. SO is not for generic "How is something done?" It's for, "Here's what I tried but it doesn't work"

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create a hidden form with inputs containing your data inside, and submit it to desired address

Example using jQuery:

```
var url = 'index.html';
var data = {
  a: 1,
  b: { a: 1, b: 2},
  c: [1, 2, 3]
};

function appendData($form, prefix, data) {
  function append(k, data) {
    if (prefix !== '') {
      appendData($form, prefix + '[' + k + ']', data[k]);
    } else {
      appendData($form, k, data[k]);
    }
  }
  if (data instanceof Object) {
    if ($.isArray(data)) {
      for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
        append(i, data);
      }
    } else {
      for (var k in data) {
        append(k, data);
      }
    }
  } else {
    var inp = $('<input type="hidden" name="' + prefix + '">').val(data);
    $form.append(inp);
  }
}
var $form = $('<form style="display:none;" action="' + url + '" method="post"/>');

appendData($form, '', data);
$('body').append($form);
$form[0].submit();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bM4oAj7TZNWfjkLVWMrY

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the phyiscal page in the browser, then you have to get the browser to do it.  You can have an AJAX in the background, but it's not going to affect the browser page.

The simpliest way to get the browser to change the page is to set the `window.location` property to the url of the new page.  Note, however, you can only do a `GET` this way.

I'd suggest doing an AJAX POST, and have that return a URL which you can have the borowser get to display the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a Read at this . Hope it helps ...

http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-Pass-Data-Values-from-one-page-to-another-using-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to get to a predefined page and transfer a data packet you can encode the data into the query string if it's only a small amount.

Alternatively you can store it with HTML 5 local storage, change window.location to load the new page and then get the info back from the local storage.